# How to use Postman to authenticate Google Login with dj_rest_auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, google-signin, dj-rest-auth

So I am following the official documentation for Google sign in with DjangoRestFramework using DJ Rest Auth ([this link](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#google))

I intend to authenticate with Postman Oauth2 (by following the guide and generating an Access Token)
[image: postman oauth page]
Postman is generating an access token successfully, but I cannot seem to use this authentication in my API calls. Please who knows which step I am missing - I want to handle everything in Postman.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('accounts/', include(api_urls, namespace='api')),
path('accounts/login/', GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google_login'),
path('accounts/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
callback_url = 'http://localhost:8080/accounts/google/login/callback/'
client_class = OAuth2Client
```

On calling an API endpoint, I get an `invalid token` error:
[image: invalid token]

If I however visit the Google Login view in my  RestFramework UI (in my case `http://localhost:8080/accounts/login`), I get an endpoint to make a POST, and on making a POST request, a key is generated. Only this key (if used as a Bearer token) works in my API calls.
[image: Google View]
[image: Key generated]

How can I authenticate on Google, and make my API calls independent of the DRF UI?
Callback URL has been configured on my Google Developer Client.

*PS: I feel the answer is in step 6 of the documentation, but I am unable to figure out how to do this in Postman*

`POST code or token to specified URL(/dj-rest-auth/google/)`

Answer (score 0):

What I did here is from postman go to headers then put Authorization = Token youraccesskey

which in your case Authorization = Token ef057......
Hope it helps